# Batch R Script - setting the working directory and selecting output folder

Tags: r, batch-file, working-directory

I've been digging into several places for 2 simple needs but couldn't find a final answer.

I'm running an R script in batch mode. Not sure whether my solution is the best one but I'm using R CMD BATCH as per http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/BATCH.html included in a bat file.

First I'd like to have the directory where the R script is saved set up as the working directory rather than where the bat file is saved.

Secondly I'd like to divert all the output from the R script (csv files and charts) to a specific directory other than the working directory. I cannot find any options for such basic requirement.

The final idea is to be able to run the bat file across different computers no matter where the R script is saved.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't give code so my answer will be just an advise or what I would do for such job.

1. Use `Rscript.exe` it is the way to go for batch script. R CMD is a sort of legacy tool.
2. You don't need to set or change the working directory. It is a source of problems
3. You can launch you bat file where you want and within it you go to R script location using cd for example you bat file can be like:

   ```
   cd R_SCRIPT_PATH
   Rscript youscript.R arg1 arg2
   ```
4. You can use one of the script argument as an output directory for your result files. For example inside your script you do somehing like this:

   ```
   args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
   resultpath <- as.character(args[1])
   .....
   write.table(res1, file=paste(resultpath,'res1.csv',sep='/')
   ```