# Project Root in RStudio is not the same when running from the command line using here package

Tags: r

I use a mixture of windows and linux to develop my scripts so I wanted an easy way of keep track of the file paths without having to set them.

I use the `here` package which seems to work really well until I run something from the command line.

All my files are stored in the project directory so I don't have any issues with external files.

Example.
My linux project lives in: `/home/ubuntu/work/`
On Windows it's: `c\work\`

within RStudio both of these are fine when I use `here`, so if I call another script I use `source(here("expected_value.R"))` and this works on both platforms.

When I run from the script from the command line in linux

`Rscript /home/ubuntu/work/script.R`

The root directory now switches to `/home/ubuntu`

I mostly develop on Windows, push to git and then pull it on my linux server so I need some kind of consistency.

Comment: Where `here` ends depends on whether the package `here` is loaded in RStudio that has opened a project, RStudio that has opened a script, but not in a project, and, for R started from the command line, what the working directory is.

Comment: @MrGumble is there a way to tell `here` to use the location of the files it sits in as the root folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/here/versions/1.0.1/topics/here) that

> #### Project Root
>
> The project root is established with a call to `here::i_am()`. Although not recommended, it can be changed by calling `here::i_am()` again.
>
> In the absence of such a call (e.g. for a new project), starting with
> the current working directory during package load time, the directory
> hierarchy is walked upwards until a directory with at least one of the
> following conditions is found:
>
> contains a file `.here`
>
> contains a file matching `[.]Rproj$` with contents matching ^Version: in
> the first line
>
> contains a file `DESCRIPTION` with contents matching ^Package:
>
> contains a file `remake.yml`
>
> contains a file `.projectile`
>
> contains a directory `.git`
>
> contains a file `.git` with contents matching `^gitdir`:
>
> contains a directory `.svn`

and that

> This package is intended for interactive use only.

When you write that you use the command line, it is unclear whether you are calling R in a scripted manner or that you are loading R for interactive use, from the command line. So it is very difficult to determine why you end up with different results. I will again point out that

> Where `here` ends depends on whether the package here is loaded in RStudio that has opened a project, RStudio that has opened a script, but not in a project, and, for R started from the command line, what the working directory is.

because you haven't answered where you are starting R relative to the supposed project root.

Comment: I have updated my question regarding your comments.

Comment: When you run the command line `Rscript /home/ubuntu/work/script.R`, which directory are you?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? It is ran via a cron job

Comment: Every (or most) processes on linux runs from a "working directory". It is from that path that the current process (R) will be looking for files. The cron job is likely simply starting in your home directory (`/home/ubuntu`). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810879/batch-r-script-setting-the-working-directory-and-selecting-output-folder